# Unable to get master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb to insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb sp to pull data from multiple databases. The select query works fine, however when I attempt to insert it into a table, it kicks back an error. How would I get it to insert each result into a table I created?

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'master' to data type int.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
Insert INTO Connstrings.dbo.Results(host_name,user_name,program_name,request_duration_ms,[database])
select s.host_name, s.original_login_name AS user_name, s.program_name, 
(DATEDIFF (ms,last_request_end_time, last_request_start_time )) AS request_duration_ms, DB_NAME() AS [database]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
on r.session_id = s.session_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[database]` column in Connstrings.dbo.Results table is of type `INT`. Either change the table definition:

```
alter table Results alter column [database] sysname
```

Or change the query:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
Insert INTO Connstrings.dbo.Results(host_name,user_name,program_name,request_duration_ms,[database])
select s.host_name, s.original_login_name AS user_name, s.program_name, 
(DATEDIFF (ms,last_request_end_time, last_request_start_time )) AS request_duration_ms, DB_ID() AS [database]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
on r.session_id = s.session_id'
```